# Validation error:The file could not be found in the app package

Tags: microsoft-teams, teams-toolkit

[Validation error: The file could not be found in the app package](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RfPJA.png)

Comment: We get this error whenever there is a mismatch between the outline and color icon names in the manifest and actual files within folder. Please check and make sure you give the exact names of these .png files.

Comment: Thanks @Meghana-MSFT, this helped me in the right direction :)

Answer (score 0):

When visual studio built the app it downloaded a zip file and in that zip file it omitted two files outline.png and color.png. My solution was to copy these two files into the zip folder. I think this is not a good solution